# Redirect Subdomain to working HTTPS-Tomcat (with NGINX)

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, nginx, https

I have a working tomcat-webapplication at https://very-ugly-and-anoying-domain-name.com:8443/webdir/index.xhtml

Now I want to shorten it to https://appname.nice.com, so it redirects to my internal https://very-ugly-and-anoying-domain-name.com:8443/appname/

For all other applications, I use Nginx to redirect a subdomain http://appname.nice.com to http://very-ugly-and-anoying-domain-name.com:8081/appname/ with

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    appname.nice.com;
   location / {
      proxy_pass               http://ugly-looooooooooong.domain.com:8081;
      proxy_set_header         Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
   root /data/www/appname;
   error_page 403 404 502 503 504 /error.html;
   location /error.html {
       allow all;
       internal;
   }
}
```

But I never had the topic of redirecting a https connection. I think need NOT the stuff of adding the keystore to Nginx because it's already in tomcat.

I do not need HTTP to HTTPS or HTTPS to HTTP. Maybe there is a way to set this directly in Tomcat, but I am not so used to tomcat-config.

How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your config doesn't do a "redirect", it simply [proxies](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) the request to the host with the "ugly" domain name. For redirect, you would have to return a specific redirect code. For HTTPS, you would need a certificate which has the domain name `appname.nice.com` in its [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) field because the SSL handshake will look for it. Configure the virtual server with `ssl on` and use that certificate to terminate SSL. Then you can use a similar config to proxy the HTTPS request to the "ugly" domain name.